# Android Room extend default database

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-room, android-library

Good day Stackers.

Say you have to declare an android library with a default schema in it that has n tables like this:

```
package com.test.library.db;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import com.test.library.db.entities.defaultTable1;
import com.test.library.db.entities.defaultTable2;
import com.test.library.db.entities.defaultTableN;
import com.test.library.db.dao.DefaultTable1Dao;
import com.test.library.db.dao.DefaultTable2Dao;
import com.test.library.db.dao.DefaultTableNDao;

@Database(entities = {
        defaultTable1.class,
        defaultTable2.class,
        defaultTableN.class
}, version = 1)

public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract DefaultTable1Dao defaultTable1Dao();
    public abstract DefaultTable2Dao defaultTable2Dao();
    public abstract DefaultTableNDao defaultTableNDao();

}
```

Then you need to extend the default schema from the android library into the app like this:

```
package com.test.myapp.db;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import com.test.myapp.db.entities.Table1;
import com.test.myapp.db.entities.Table2;
import com.test.myapp.db.entities.TableN;
import com.test.myapp.db.dao.Table1Dao;
import com.test.myapp.db.dao.Table2Dao;
import com.test.myapp.db.dao.TableNDao;

@Database(entities = {
        Table1.class,
        Table2.class,
        TableN.class
}, version = 1)

public abstract class AppDatabase extends com.test.library.db.AppDatabase {

    public abstract Table1Dao table1Dao();
    public abstract Table2Dao table2Dao();
    public abstract TableNDao tableNDao();

}
```

Then to create the database i call:

```
import com.test.library.db.AppDatabase;
//... Singleton class ...
appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                   AppDatabase.class, "test.db")
                   .build();
```

The thing is that room doesn't seems to be able to merge the two `@Database` annotations (obvious), and it only takes the tables inside the last declaration of `@Database` inside `com.test.myapp.db.AppDatabase`.

So i have tried to inherit the `@Database` annotation using `@Inherit` annotation into a custom annotation similar to this:

```
package com.test.library.db;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import com.test.library.db.entities.defaultTable1;
import com.test.library.db.entities.defaultTable2;
import com.test.library.db.entities.defaultTableN;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Inherited
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Database(entities = {
        defaultTable1.class,
        defaultTable2.class,
        defaultTableN.class
}, version = 1)
public @interface CoreDatabase {}
```

And then annotate with `@CoreDatabase` the `com.test.library.db.AppDatabase` class but it seems that room doesn´t allow to annotate the `@CoreDatabase` with `@Database` annotation.

I also know that it is possible to create the default schema at the library, discard `com.test.myapp.db.AppDatabase` and then create the rest of the database using SQLite scripts or migrations, but this is less likely to be ideal since it makes harder to maintain the inherited database, and may be Room won't allow to create tables without it's matching mapping class, so...

Is there a way to wrap the `@Database` annotation like with the meta-annotation `@JacksonAnnotationInside`? or something, or what else can be done to achieve something similar to this?

Thanks a lot, and have a nice day.

Comment: Could you get a way to do it somehow, or is it possible to use multiple databases in your scenario?